# Integrating MS Power BI w/ Python / Django

Tags: python, django, powerbi, adal

I am writing a Django multi-tenant web application which is supposed to use Power BI Embedded as a reporting frontend (basically to render data from the local DB). For this, I am using the 'App Owns Data' scenario and created an application in Azure which I can authenticate against Active Directory to retrieve an access token.

However, all the code samples I found are 1) not in Python or 2) they don't work. I am wondering if anyone successfully used ADAL or the Azure libraries to connect and then the Power BI libraries to render a report?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this. Microsoft Azure itself has a sample for authenticating python apps against AAD. This should be what you are looking for: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/data-lake-analytics-python-auth-options/

Check also this sample: https://github.com/snobu/powerbi-embed-v2

And this thread: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Access-Power-BI-API-with-Python/td-p/189165

Answer (score 1):

Just for the information, If you are using Django version >= 4.1, they have introduced [SecurityMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/middleware/) that disables third-party cookies. As a result, you may encounter issues with the Power BI embedded iframe. I struggled with this.

to allow third-party cookies you may need to configure `SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY` in settings.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35461415)